# Gambling in video games with virtual currency

Tags: gambling

There is a game called Forza Horizon 4. In this game we pay to enter in race and the winner gets the reward. But the money is virtual not real. So, is it haram or halal?

Answer (score 1):

This is highly makruh in Islam. Even though the gambling is in the game, it can lead one to pay for the in-game purchases and literally gamble their REAL money. And this virtual gambling can lead one to really lottery gambling. So avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

This is haram because it will become a habit I use to play far cry 3 and that had poker in it. It's best to stay away from that brother. Allah knows best.

Comment: I would say it is certainly makruh for the same reason; it can only be considered haram with a concrete reference.